# Why is JQuery on() event handler not catching events from dynamically generated elements using contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I am dynamically generating `<p>` tags inside of a `<div contenteditable=true>` but the event handler I have setup to catch the keyup events coming from the `<p>` tags is not catching them.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Non-dynamically generated paragraph -->
<div class="note">
    <p contenteditable="true"></p>
</div>

<!-- Contains dynamically generated paragraphs -->
<div class="note" contenteditable="true"></div>

<!-- Debug output -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".note").keyup(function(evt) {
        $("#output").append("<br/>note tag keyup");
        // Surround paragraphs with paragraph tag
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).wrap('<p class="test"></p>');
    });

    $(".note").on("keyup", "p", function(evt) {
        $("#output").append("<br/>p tag keyup");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mibacode/axgccwoq/3/

The first div element demonstrates that I can successfully catch the keyup event from a paragraph tag generated on load.  The second div shows that my dynamically generated paragraphs are not firing (or JQuery just can't catch) the `keyup` event.

---

**Edit:**

The issue/bug appears to be with how the paragraph tags are being generated and added to the DOM in this portion of the code:

```
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<p class="test"></p>');
```

I believe for some the `<p>` tag isn't being added properly so the DOM isn't recognizing it or doesn't know it exists.

---

**Edit 2:**
I replaced the jQuery functionality which inserts the new paragraph tags with vanilla JS in hopes that might solve my issue, however it did not.

New code:

```
var textNode = null;
var nodes = this.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3)
    {
        textNode = nodes[i];
        break;
    }
}
if (textNode)
{
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    var attr = document.createAttribute("contenteditable");
    attr.value = "true";
    p.setAttributeNode(attr);
    p.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        $("#output").append("<br/>Special paragraph click!");
    });
    p.innerHTML = textNode.nodeValue;
    var parent = $(this)[0];
    parent.insertBefore(p, textNode);
    parent.removeChild(textNode);
}
```

It appears it has to do with the way that JS handles events fired from elements within contenteditable elements.

Comment: Use $('body').on('keyup', '.note p', function(){});

Comment: @FredrikL - there's no reason that would work over what the OP already has. OP - what's the sense in trying to capture a keyup event on a paragraph, rather than an input?

Comment: I think the problem is that the browser doesn't generate keyboard events for `<p>` elements; they're not interactive.

Comment: @Pointy It does, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/kgt1kst5/

Comment: @mb595x oh ok, because it's in a `contenteditable` block, durr that makes sense of course.

Comment: [Here's a fork of your fiddle with a style change for the `<p>` - it works for me at least. (JavaScript code is unchanged.)](https://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/koacnfe7/)

Comment: @AramilRey My code shows that I am already using the on() event as stated as the solutions for that question.  My issue is that the on event isn't working.

Comment: @Pointy It doesn't work for me.  When I press a key in the bottom div, it still only outputs "note tag keyup".  If it was working it would output "p tag keyup" as well.

Comment: @mb595x OK yes I see that now. Well it seems like the problem isn't a jQuery issue; the browser fires those keyboard events with the surrounding `<div>` as the target. Thus the delegated `.on()` handler's selector does not match the target of the event, so the handler is not run.

Comment: I can see the issue now, contenteditable isn't delegating events, if you add the contenteditable attribute to your first div, dinamic or no dinamic will behave the same, its not about that, its about the contenteditable attribute

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you don't have the `contenteditable` attribute on the dynamic `<p>` tags. Just because they are contained within a `contenteditable` element doesn't make them editable also - they need the attribute explicitly.

In my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axgccwoq/1/), I have simplified it just to show that the dynamic tags work.

Comment: While I see it works in your fiddle, I updated my fiddle to add the `contenteditable="true"` to the paragraph tags but I still do not get the expected output.

Comment: @mb595x: I see what you mean. I'm not sure why, but it seems that the parent `contenteditable` attribute interferes with the children, like it gets the event instead. If you add `$(this).attr('contenteditable', false);` to the event handler, all the subsequent events are handled correctly.